# Cycles in Kneser graphs with three vertices forming triangles

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs, cycles, kneser-graph

Consider the Kneser graphs $G=K(n,k)$. Is it possible to list how many even cycles, or, at the least, existence of an even cycle of a given order in $G$, such that any three consecutive vertices form a triangle?

For [Odd graphs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_graph) having $(n-k)\ge3$, as these are triangle free, the answer would be none. But, suppose $n=7a,k=2a$, for positive $a$. Then, is it possible to say that these contain all even cycles of order $\ge12$ such that any three consecutive vertices induce a triangle? A more stronger version would be, if the square (in the distance sense) of any cycle of order $\ge12$ is an induced subgraph of the Kneser graphs $G$ with $n=7a,k=2a$? Any hints?

Comment: by all even cycles you mean of all even lengths not exceeding ${n\choose k}$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov yes, definitely

Comment: Also, what does "Odd graphs of having $n-k\ge 3$" mean?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I meant [Odd graphs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_graph) having $(n-k)\ge3$. Added the same in question

Comment: But Kneser graph is triangle free if $n<3k$, that is less restrictive than $n=2k+1$ as in Odd graph. If $n=3k$, every edge belongs to a unique triangle, so such cycles of length $>3$ also do not exist.

Comment: @FedorPetrov thanks for pointing that out. So what about the case $n>3k$. Like the case I am interested in, $n=7a, k=2a$?

Comment: I expect that your claim is correct, and not only for even lengths of cycles

Comment: @FedorPetrov any idea of proof?

Comment: If we place the elements around a circle and consider a subgraph on $n$ vertices formed by consecutive $k$'s, it is easy to get a cycle on them. Then we possibly may partition all vertices on such subgraph and jump between them. This is quite naive, of course. Maybe clever design constructions ideas must be applied.